# Can H2O (from the R package h2o) save and reload training data?

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I am trying to do deep learning using `H2O` via the R package `h2o`,
and want to ask whether `H2O` can save and reload training data for future additional training?

My code:

```
iris.train <- irisdata[-1,]
iris.test <- irisdata[1,]

res.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5_offset, data = iris.train, activation = "Rectifier")
pred.dl <- h2o.predict(object=res.dl, newdata=iris.test)
res.err.dl[i] <- ifelse(as.character(as.matrix(pred.dl)[1,1]) == as.character(as.matrix(iris.test)[1,5]),0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h2o.saveModel(object, dir = "", name = "", filename = "", force = FALSE)
```

and

```
h2o.loadModel(path, conn = h2o.getConnection())
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example that I've used recently while building a deep learning model in version 2.8.6 in h2o.The model was saved in hdfs.For latest version you probably have to remove the classification=T switch and have to replace data with training_frame

```
library(h2o)
h = h2o.init(ip="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port=54321, startH2O = F)

cTrain.h2o <- as.h2o(h,cTrain,key="c1")
cTest.h2o <- as.h2o(h,cTest,key="c2")

nh2oD<-h2o.deeplearning(x =c(1:12),y="tgt",data=cTrain.h2o,classification=F,activation="Tanh",
                        rate=0.001,rho=0.99,momentum_start=0.5,momentum_stable=0.99,input_dropout_ratio=0.2,                        
                        hidden=c(12,25,11,11),hidden_dropout_ratios=c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4),
                        epochs=150,variable_importances=T,seed=1234,reproducible = T,l1=1e-5,
                        key="dn")

hdfsdir<-"hdfs://xxxxxxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/xxxxx/models"

h2o.saveModel(nh2oD,hdfsdir,name="DLModel1",save_cv=T,force=T)

test=h2o.loadModel(h,path=paste0(hdfsdir,"/","DLModel1"))
```